# Easy controller registration for nuget package

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Im trying to make it easy to register a controller in a nuget package.

```
public static class ServicesConfigurationExtention
 {
    public static void AddMyPackageWithController(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<AnotherClass>();

        var builder = services.AddMvcCore();
            builder.AddApplicationPart(typeof(MyController).Assembly);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to just register the controller without calling AddMvcCore?

Comment: Hi @tro, it seems to be impossible that `AddApplicationPart` is the extension of mvc builder. What is your scenario? Why do you want to avoid calling `AddMvcCore`?

Comment: It's for a nugget package and I would like to be able to register the controller from an extension method in the package, worried that calling AddMvcCore from a startup file that already calls add mvc could cause a conflict, or there could be a problem from potentially calling it twice. Would this be a problem?

Comment: Hi @tro, got it. I would not be a problem. BTW, but why not add these services directly in Startup.cs which can avoid add mvc twice.